# select average value of month from daily data(sum of daily/no of days)

Tags: mysql

My code is this but error in line three `mm/dd/yyyy` my database date format is like this:

```
SELECT
     evep
     year(date='MM/dd/yyyy'),
     month(date='MM/dd/yyyy'),
     Avg(evep)
FROM
     Value
GROUP BY
    evep,
     year(date='MM/dd/yyyy'),
     month(date='MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your date string to a real date

```
SELECT
     evep,
     year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')),
     month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')),
     Avg(evep)
FROM
     Value
GROUP BY
    evep,
     year(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')),
     month(str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y'));
```